# C++ Visual Studio - Interpreting memory leak detection on simple example

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, visual-studio-2013

I would like to start using the VS Memory Leak detection in C++. Since I am more used to Java, here is simple example I have problem with. I want to test simple class for leaks. Header:

```cpp
#pragma once
class Tested{
public:
    Tested();
    ~Tested();

    const int N = 10;
    const int PARS = 3;

    float* getDataLine(int n);

private:
    float** data;
};
```

Cpp file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tested.h"
using namespace std;

Tested::Tested() {
    data = new float*[N];
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        data[i] = new float[PARS];
    }
}

float* Tested::getDataLine(int n){
    return data[n];
}

Tested::~Tested() {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        delete[] data[i];
    }
    delete[] data;
}
```

stdafx.h

```
#pragma once
#include "targetver.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h"

// http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e5ewb1h3(v=vs.71).aspx
#define _CRTDBG_MAP_ALLOC
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <crtdbg.h>
#ifdef _DEBUG
    #ifndef DBG_NEW
        #define DBG_NEW new ( _NORMAL_BLOCK , __FILE__ , __LINE__ )
        #define new DBG_NEW
    #endif
#endif  // _DEBUG
```

And finally the test class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Tested.h"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace Test{
    TEST_CLASS(MemoryLeakTest){
    public:
        TEST_METHOD(AllDataAccess){
            //_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
            //_CrtSetBreakAlloc(147);
            {
                Tested t;
                float* line = t.getDataLine(0);
                line[0] = 10;
            }
            _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
        }
    };
}
```

Now, if I comment-out the line 'delete[] data;', the leak detection report is nice and points to the line where the data** is initialized:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
c:\users\j\dropbox\workspace\visualstudio\memoryleaktest\neurontest\tested.cpp(7) : {148} normal block at 0x06B09D68, 40 bytes long.
 Data: <        `       > D0 9D B0 06 18 9E B0 06 60 9E B0 06 A8 9E B0 06 
{147} normal block at 0x06B09BA8, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > F0 D9 16 0F 
Object dump complete.
```

But if I use the 'delete[] data;' (as shown), the detect output shows the following:

```
Detected memory leaks!
Dumping objects ->
{147} normal block at 0x060A72F0, 4 bytes long.
 Data: <    > F0 D9 C2 0F 
Object dump complete.
```

If I uncomment the lines in the 'TEST_METHOD()' for breakpoint on the 147 location. The debug normally exits without further information (log [here](http://pastie.org/9822169)).

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and Visual C++ Native Unit Test Project. So, my questions are:

- Is the class constructor and destructor written OK??
- The second leak deteciton - 4 bytes: what causes this and how to obtain better information about it? That is: why the breakpoint does not work?
- Does have to the block containint the 'Tested t;' end before '_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();'?
- Am I using the leak detection right? Or is there a better way how to do this??

Thanks for any input. 
Jarda

Edit: as pointed out by @Hans Passant, I've already tried adding the breakpoint and watching breakpoint variable, but neither worked and the application simply returns with code 0. If I add own breakpoint and try to watch the variable, it says that is not found, as seen [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/atgpnxhj4c0b77d/leak.PNG?dl=0). Note that I am not sure which C++ the VS uses.

Edit2: Since there was multiple questions and most of them were solved, I will mark this as solved question and the one unsolved separately.

Thanks

Comment: No need for leak detection when using stl containers ;) (vector in this case)

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/151585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is the class constructor and destructor written OK??

It appears to be technically correct, however it is written in 'old fashioned' C++. If you change your `data` member to `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` then memory management is all taken care of for you. You shouldn't really be writing new C++ code with `new` and `delete`.

> The second leak deteciton - 4 bytes: what causes this and how to obtain better information about it?

The CRT probably needs to allocate memory itself for the breakpoint which it doesn't deallocate since the breakpoint needs to remain active for the lifetime of the program.

> Does have to the block containint the 'Tested t;' end before '_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();'?

Yes, the destructor is called on the `}` line. This is why it is also recommended to call `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);` instead so that the memory leaks are dumped at program exit after all automatic destructors have been called.

> Am I using the leak detection right? Or is there a better way how to do this??

If you are using MSVC it makes sense to do it with the built in tools. If you use other compilers such as clang then they come with their own memory validation tools and if you are running on Linux then you can detect leaks with valgrind. But since you are using Microsoft's compiler it makes sense to use their tools for this.

Comment: Thank you for your answers @sjdowling, all is explained except this:

The 4 bytes leak is reported in the code as is displayed, that is no breakpoints are set and everything deleted (seemingly) OK. If I comment-out `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` and add `_CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
   _CrtSetBreakAlloc(147);` absolutely nothing happens (even if I cause another memory leak).